# How do I catch Charizard, Bulbasaur, Squirtle and Pikachu on Pokemon Platinum?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

The question is pretty self-explaining. Is there a way to catch these Pokemon on Platinum? On a low level preferably in order to train them with good stats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Charmander**, **Bulbasaur**, and **Squirtle** cannot be caught in Pokémon Platinum, likewise for all of their evolution chain. They can only be obtained by trading from a different game. You can either get them through FireRed/LeafGreen via Pal Park (a place to trade Pokémon from the 3rd generation), or you can obtain them in HeartGold/SoulSilver and trade them over.

**Pikachu** can be found at Trophy Garden, which is the grass behind the Pokémon Mansion south of Hearthome. They should be available at all times, if my memory serves correctly. I believe they're no higher than 20, which is plenty sufficient to get all the EVs you need.

---

A note, however, is that you don't need to worry a lot about levels on non-legendary Pokémon that you catch. Any breed-capable Pokémon can be hatched from an egg, which results in a new one starting at level 1. This is also advantageous as you can use breeding to get a better moveset than naturally possible. So even if circumstances result that you can only trade a fully levelled one of any of these 4 Pokémon, you can always breed it to get a low level one ripe for your own training needs.

Comment: In Diamond/Pearl/Platinum and onward, eggs hatch at level 1.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for that. I have incorporated that into an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The three starters aren't available in Platinum, although you can get one in HeartGold/SoulSilver from Professor Oak after defeating Red.

Pikachu can be found in the Trophy Garden behind Mr. Backlot's mansion.

You can get the three starters in Platinum using Wi-Fi trade, providing you've seen them in-game. I don't know if any trainer in Platinum has Bulbasaur, Charmander or Squirtle. There are trainers with these Pokemon in HeartGold and SoulSilver.

Comment: Yes you can definitely see them (or their evolutions) in-game, because that's exactly how I got them.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, you cannot get them unless, like said before, you must trade them from another pokemon game.I'm pretty sure the games you need are heartgold and soul silver. And I know I'm late to answer this but I don't care I hope that you did figure this out and by now you probably already got them so, good for you!